# React <canvas/> tag drawImage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Im trying to create a canvas in react that can be drawn on. For the canvas i want to have an image on it called `Dogimage` which is drawn on, this image is stored in another folder in my directory with the path `../../images/dog-without-labels.png` . I already have the drawing working, but i cant seem to load the image onto the canvas as nothing shows up on the canvas.

this is some of my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";



function DrawCanvas() {

    const canvasRef = useRef(null)
    const contextRef = useRef(null)
    const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false)
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)


    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth/1.5 ;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight/1.5 ;
        canvas.style.width = `${window.innerWidth/3}px`;
        canvas.style.height = `${window.innerHeight/3}px`;

        const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
        context.scale(2,2)
        context.lineCap = "round"
        context.lineWidth = 3
        context.strokeStyle = "black"
        //const image = new Image();
        const Dogimage = document.createElement('img');
        Dogimage.src = '../../images/dog-without-labels.png'
        Dogimage.onload = () => setImage(Dogimage)

        context.drawImage(Dogimage, 0, 0,400,256+80);
        
        contextRef.current = context
        
    }, [])
```

Any advice on how i can load the image onto the canvas?

Comment: you are using drawimage on an image that has not yet been downloaded. I'm not posting an answer because reactjs may change the answer. but I'ld place the context.drawImage in the setImage function which you have not posted. And, then it would work in the browser but reactjs may want ???

Comment: @Wayne setImage is a useState function i.e `const [image, setImage] = useState(null)`, your suggestion didnt work unfortunately

Comment: /* reactjs thats why i didn't post an answer */ Create a function you can call after the image is loaded to drawImage. I'd make context a global variable ... not scoped within the function. But you could onload = useImage and useImage(() => { /* setImage ... drawImage */ } within the scope of Drawcanvas

Comment: Am I to understand you can not setImage(Dogimage) before the image is loaded as well?

Comment: Dogimage.onload = () => { setImage(Dogimage); context.drawImage(Dogimage, 0, 0,400,256+80); }